# Why is the image of an element in $\mathbb Q(\zeta_m, \zeta_p)$ under an automorphism of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_m)$ defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-numbers

[image]

This is a part of page 214 in Ireland and Rosen's "A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory". $p$ is a prime coprime to $m$, $\zeta_m = e^{\frac{2\pi i}m}$, $D_m$ is the ring of integers of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_m)$, $f$ is the least positive integer for which $p^f = 1 \mod m$, $g(P)$ is the gauss sum belonging to the $F = D_m / P$ characters $\chi (\gamma + P) = 1/(\gamma/P)_m, \psi (t) = \zeta_p ^{t + t^p + t^{p^2} + \dots + t^{p^{f-1}}}$, $\Phi(P) = g(P)^m$, and for all $1\le t < m$ coprime to $m$ $\sigma_t \in G(\mathbb Q (\zeta_m), \mathbb Q)$ is the automorphism that maps $\zeta_m$ to $\zeta_m ^t$.

Why can we talk about $g(P)^{\sigma_{t'}}$ if $g(P)$ doesn't belong to $\mathbb Q(\zeta_m)$? Assuming we can, why is $\sigma_{t'} (\psi (r))$ equal to $\psi (r)$? I assume it should follow from $\sigma _{t'} (\psi (r)) = \psi (r) ^{t'}$, but I don't see why that should be the case given that $\psi(r)$ is a $p$th root of unity (and not an $m$th one).

Comment: What is $\Phi(P)$ again, is it supposed to be an element of $O_{\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_m)}$ (the notation $D_m$ is awful) ? $\sigma_{t'}$ for integer $t'$ seems to mean the automorphism of $\bigcup_{\gcd(t',l)=1} \Bbb{Q}(\zeta_l)$ sending each $\zeta_l$ to $\zeta_l^{t'}$.

Comment: @reuns  the notation $\Phi(P)$ is a power of a Gauss sum (the power whose prime ideal factorization is given by Stickelberger's theorem). I agree with you that the notation $D_m$ is awful and I have strongly urged the OP multiple times to study algebraic number theory from a more fleshed out account than the one in Ireland & Rosen, but it seems the OP won't consider that advice.

Comment: @reuns $\Phi (P)$ is $g(P)^m$. What do you mean by an automorphism of the union?

Comment: Just the big cyclotomic field containing all roots of unity of order coprime with $t'$. Your definition of $\psi(t)$ is sloppy as $t+t^p+\ldots t^{p^{f-1}}$ doesn't have to be an integer, don't use the letter $t$ and use the notation $\psi(r)=\zeta_p^{Tr(r)}$ where $Tr(r)=Tr_{O_{\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_m)}/P \ / \Bbb{F}_p}(r)$. Is it obvious that $g(P)^m \in O_{\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_m)}$ ?

Comment: Why would such an automorphism exist? The last claim is proven in the book.